# How to retain POST data during pagination in spring-mvc controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, pagination

I'm using `spring` and `thymeleaf` templating engine. On the page I have a form that submits the data as `POST` request.

And shows the result in a table. The table should get pagination options, and on click changes the url eg to:
`http://localhost:8080/test?page=2&pageSize=10`

Problem: when I click the button link and call the get query above, then the POST data from previous search is lost.

Question: how can I retain the POSTed data during pagination?

```
@Controller
public class PageController {
        @GetMapping("/persons")
        private String test(org.springframework.ui.Model model) {
               model.addAttribute("dto", new FormDTO());
               return "persons"; //returns persons.html
        }

        @PostMapping(@ModelAttribute("dto") FormDTO dto,
            @RequestParam(value = "pageSize", required = false) Optional<Integer> pageSize,
            @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Optional<Integer> page,
            org.springframework.ui.Model model) {
         persons = dao.findByFirstnameAndLastname(form.getFirstname(), form.getLastname());
         model.addAttribute("persons", persons);
         return "persons";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean that, you have to retain your `FormDTO` data for you POST mapping?

Comment: Dou you need only change url (and stay on the same page), or reload page with another url?

Comment: I need to update most of the page content (which consists mainly of the data table as a result of the query).

Comment: Yes, when the pagination button is clicked, I have to retain the `FormDTO`. Because the form was posted prior, but the pagination is a `GET` request (via url query params).

Comment: What about ajax request?

Comment: Probably I can't do proper ajax with `thymeleaf`.

Comment: @membersound I'm a bit confused. What controller do you call when you click pagination button? I though you are requesting to `@PostMapping` in `PageController` for pagination. If you send `GET` request for pagination and try to retain `FormDTO` then you need to pass the data to that controller and bind data in it.